# Converting HTML to XML and back without external tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, asp.net-mvc, xmlhttprequest

I'm kind of stuck here. I'm developing a `client (Zentrick) app` that only supports `XmlHttpRequests` (`cross-platform` problems are fixed). The `client` communicates with a `ASP.NET MVC service`. My first approach was to send HTML pages to the client and then injecting them into the views. After experimenting and doing some research, I concluded my client only accepts `XML structure`. Is there a simple way to convert `HTML` to `XML` on my service and convert the `XML` to `HTML` on my client (client only supports JavaScript and basic `jQuery` (no `Ajax requests`)) in an easy way?

Comment: Are you wanting to pass entire html pages to the client, or just the data to display in them?

Comment: The entire HTML page. I think I just realised I am having cross-platform issues so I'm not sure anymore whether my client supports HTML or not.

My request throws an exception : '0x805e0006' after some research I see this means that I'm having cross-platform issues. They should be solved by adding this: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' and this 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET' (not sure if this is necessary) to the response header of the service. Is there anything else that needs to be sorted out?

Comment: Using IE or Chrome I don't get an exception (on Firefox I do get an exception) but my responseText or responseXML is "" instead of containing my data. Funny because executing the request using the REST console clearly returns the requested data.

My request: http://pastebin.com/ew2VC4c3 . Console doesn't return null but "".

Comment: After experimenting a bit more (disabling security settings, change response headers) I have managed to let my XmlHttpRequest reach ready state. The only problem that now occurs is that when I try to get my responseText, the responseText property is ''. Any suggestions?